# EF Core updating foreign key is not updating the navigation property

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I have a table called `User` that contains 3 foreign keys `CountryID` , `NationalityID` and `EducationID`

The user can update any of these foreign keys and the end point is supposed to return the updated User entity back with the details of the navigation property.

So to achieve that I did it like below

```
var user= await _dbContext.Users
.Include(x => x.Country)
.Include(x => x.Nationality)
.Include(x => x.Education)
.Where(P => P.userID == request.userId)
.AsTracking()
.FirstOrDefaultAsync();
```

Then if user wants to update I do

```
user.CountryID= request.CountryID;

user.NationalityID= request.NationalityID;

await _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();

var userDTO = _mapper.Map<UpdateUserResponseDTO>(user);
```

The problem is in the  JSON reponse the country and nationality details such as their names and other details is returned as `null`

What I did to fix it is adding

```
_dbContext.Entry(user).Reference(x => x.Country).Load();

_dbContext.Entry(user).Reference(x => x.Nationality).Load();

_dbContext.Entry(user).Reference(x => x.Education).Load();

await _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
```

But not sure what is the impact of using `load` or how `efficient` it is?
and why `asTracking` is not tracking the changes done in the navigation propriety?
And is using `Load()` more efficient rather then loading the user entity again after updating it? like doing

```
 var user= await _dbContext.Users
    .Include(x => x.Country)
    .Include(x => x.Nationality)
    .Include(x => x.Education)
    .Where(P => P.userID == request.userId)
    .FirstOrDefaultAsync();
```

Comment: Certainly the last one will be faster since it only needs one trip to the sever.  For each load you need a special trip.

Comment: isn't there a batter solution for this problem?

Comment: The best is an enemy of the good. You should be happy if everything is working propery and not to try to spoil it.

Comment: It's not enough if things are just working the quality and the code efficiency matters

Comment: When  you're doing the mapping, you could update the navigational property with the actual values of the new relationship. So map User.Nationality to the new Nationality instance that you're setting.

The problem being, as soon as you update that id, it will need to load up it's entry into to memory which will need another db call at some point if that navigational property is important.

Comment: @scottdavidwalker So in case user is updating Country , Nationality and Education all at once I have to hit the SQL server 3 times for each. So I think the last solution provided in the question is better right?

Comment: I would take a presumption that .Include is more efficient based on the use case you've shown. Using .Load will make individual calls to the database whereas .Include will do a join (unless you've got virtual navigational properties in which case they will be lazy loaded)

Comment: But Include here didn't solve the problem

Comment: The problem, is that you want ef to load the new entity in the background when you change the foreign key. To do this, you'll need to re-retrieve the data, either via .Load, or doing another get with the .Includes. I would go for the latter.
FYI, your AsTracking isn't doing anything. EF tracks by default

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to add virtual keyword in your Context class before any Dbset Property to be like this

```
public virtual DbSet<type> propname {get;set;}
```

And also add virtual keyword before the navigation properties in your domain classes to be like that

```
public class User
{
public virtual Country Country {get;set;} 
}
public class Country 
{
public virtual ICollection<User> Users {get;set;} 
}
```

These configurations would help entity framework to inherit your navigation properties and apply the lazy loading over them

Comment: So you no longer need to call the load methods. You can also try the default tracking way by changing the entry status to modified after updating the user country and nationality ids

Comment: For instance dbcontext.Entry(User object ).State=EntityState.Modifided